# Artalk XMPP library questions

Tags: c#, xmpp

I used [Artalk XMPP](https://github.com/araditc/Artalk.Xmpp/tree/master/Artalk.Xmpp) nuget package in my C# application. I was able to send messages from the user account `userA@domain.com` to the user account `userB@domain.com` through Ignite OpenFire server on our LAN. There were several minor issues with the messages that are not showstoppers:

- If I tried to provide a subject, it was prefixed with the word "Subject: " in the client. This is not a problem but I am wondering if this is a remote client or server thing.
- The message body was wrapped in square brackets as [test message body]. This is not a big problem but I would rather avoid it, to preserve the message being sent as-is, for the possible automatic processing. Is this a remote client or server thing?
- If message body contained XML, then it was sent successfully but never received. Is sending XML not allowed by XMPP protocol? Or is it a server or remote client thing?

Edit:

Since I asked the above bullet, I tried to use `System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape()` on the message body and wrapped it in `<![CDATA[]]>` and it was delievered with its XML preserved. The question still stands.

- All successfully delivered messages have been also copied by `userB` back to `userA`. This is all right if `userA` is not interactive, but if it is also a real human being, then it may be annoying. Is this a server or remote client thing, and is there any way to avoid it? I know that the remote user's client does not do it with regular chat messages sent through a Jabber client to them.

Next, I had `userB@domain.com` invite `userA@domain.com` to a chat room `conference.domain.com@conference.domain.com` and tried to send messages to that chat room, still from `userA@domain.com`. No messages have been received in the conference room, and there was no exception thrown during the sending.

```
ArtalkXmppClient xmpp;
xmpp = new ArtalkXmppClient("domain.com", "userA@domain.com", "secret", 5222, true);

try
{
    var msg = new Message(
        "conference.domain.com@conference.domain.com",
        "test message body",
        "conference subject", // conference allows participants to change subject
        null,
        MessageType.Groupchat, 
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    if (!xmpp.Connected)
    {
        xmpp.Connect("myapp");
    }

    xmpp.SendMessage(msg);

    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the group chat part of the question was to pre-create the group on the server before trying to send to it and to use `MessageType.Chat`.

The last part was counter-intuitive and I would have never figured it out, if I did not forget to enable group chat in the configuration during testing. When using `MessageType.GroupChat` or any type other than `Chat` it simply did not work.

Also, subject must be `null`, otherwise subject will change but no messages will be delivered. Changes of subject have to be sent on their own, separate messages without bodies.

The only side effect that I am noticing is that with group chat, as opposed to person-to-person chat, the messages appear escaped. I am not sure what escapes them as opposed to person-to-person chat, but this is kind of acceptable.